Independent cartoon shown in Canada
There was a cartoon that I think I saw on CBC's zed programme. This alien baby was taken in by a couple, and all it says is "peanut", and eventually brings thousands of other aliens to live there.


Strange Invaders (2002)

Doris is eager to get pregnant, so she picks up her husband Roger and
  has her way with him. Their lovemaking comes to the attention of space
  aliens, who beam a small child-like creature into their living room,
  with a crash. Doris is delighted; for her, it's the child she's always
  wanted. 
But the lad, who says only the word "peanut", eats plates and
  goldfish, pulls utensils apart for the wiring, and in a short time,
  has built a device that may bring more like him to earth.

~ DVD Cover from Filmoteca HawkmenBlues
Watch the short here or here.

Yes! Thank you, you're awesome!
